# Interactive R Notebooks/Dashboards for Non-R Users

Tags: r, r-markdown

Not sure this is the right place for this kind of question, but I am looking for ideas on how to share some R Markdown Notebooks with non-R users, but that still have some dynamic functionality in them. For example, I can create a notebook with html-widgets to adjust time windows, choose different data points, etc. I compile this in R Studio and it looks great on my machine. But sharing the .nb.html file with co-workers, they don't get the same level of interactivity, which is expected.

Is there a way to share these files or similar R files with non-R users? Additionally, I don't have access to a personal/company website where I could host these notebooks.

Comment: Would you be interested in creating a [`shiny` app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/)?

Comment: for example DT package gives your rmd html¸ output filterable data frames , you can also use plotly() to have interactiv plots (easy for everybodey using  ggplotly() ), further check out flexdashboards https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/  as well as sematic dashb. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/semantic.dashboard/semantic.dashboard.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could for example use :

- DT package to give your Rmd output filter- able html data frames .
- you can also use plotly() to have interactiv plots [easy to do for ggplot2 users using ggplotly() ]

  further check out :
- flexdashboards https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/
- sematic dashboards. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/semantic.dashboard/semantic.dashboard.pdf

both are solutions for more dynamic Rmarkdown reports, but not as demanding to programm as full blown shiny apps.

Comment: Plotly is going to work! I knitted an RMarkdown file using the plotly library, and when I opened the resulting HTML file, the graphs were interactive. Thank you for your second answer on one of my questions mysterious user12256545